# how can i get the length of argv[1]

Tags: c, argv, strlen

not sure how I should get the string length from the argv[1], I think the problem is with the argv[i] but I can't seem to find anything to help with this

```
if(argc <2) 
{
    printf("please enter a file name!");
}
printf("%s",argv[1]);


char source[] = {argv[1]};

char destination;
int start = 0;
int len = 0;

for(int i =0; i< strlen(argv[1]);i++)
{       
    if(argv[i] != ' ')
        len++;  
}

printf("%d",len);
```

Comment: `if(argv[i] != ' ')` ===> `if(argv[1][i] != '\0')`, but `strlen(argv[1])` should be perfectly fine.

Comment: The argument string does not end in `' '` but in `'\0'`. It *cannot* end in (or contain) a `' '` unless the caller placed the argument in "quotes".

Comment: `strlen(argv[1])` already gives the length of that arg. Unless you mean the arg is multi-word. It's best if you provide an exact command line and the expected result.

Comment: `char source[] = {argv[1]};` You cannot initialize a `char` array with a `char *`. That is only possible with string literals. This line should give some compiler warning. The result is a single `char` value holding part of the pointer.